# GUI for PyVisa code

Tags: python, tkinter

I am looking for some instruction on Tkinter.  I have a simple Visa program to return the identification of a piece of test equipment.  I am looking to be able to have a Tkinter GUI that I can enter the GPIB Adress which defines a variable (addr) for the code.  When pushing a button, the returned string would be displayed.  Does anyone have a sample of code for this or a good tutorial on this?  My visa code is:

```
    import visa
    rm = visa.ResourceManager()
    rm.list_resources()
    ('ASRL1::INSTR', 'ASRL2::INSTR', 'GPIB0::' + str(addr) + '::INSTR')
    my_instrument = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::' + str(addr) + '::INSTR')
    instr = my_instrument.query('*IDN?')
    print (instr)
```

Comment: Have you googled any of this? This is a common topic in tutorials and is available all over the net. I would go to youtube and search tutorials on tkinter entry widgets

Comment: I have googled some, just new to this.  I have found how to make buttons and entry boxes, but have been struggling to find how to make the code run when the button is pressed.

Comment: This shows none of the attempts you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your issue in the comment.

> been struggling to find how to make the code run when the button is pressed

The way you get data from entry fields is with `get()` and the way you can use a button to access this data is by providing a command or a link to a function/method that can do this work.

See below code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application():
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master

        self.entry1 = Entry(self.master)
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.button1 = Button(self.master, text = "Print Entry", command = self.print_entry)
        self.button1.pack()

    def print_entry(self):
        print(self.entry1.get())

root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

this is a simple example that will provide an entry filed and a button. The button will run the method called `print_entry` that will then print the content of the `self.entry1` widget.

Its as simple as that. You can do what ever you want with the string you get from `self.entry1.get()` but my example just uses print for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, this gives me a good starting point and helps with my understanding.

Comment: I have made an update above to my original question, do you have any suggestions on  a way to make the response come back into the text box instead of the shell?  Thanks, Joe.

Comment: @Joe.M Let me know when you post your question. I have the answer you need for it.